# Responsive SVG text full div

Tags: html, svg, response

I am trying to render a text of max length 5 on a div with dynamic height and  width, I need it to be rendered full screen responsively filling the entire div area.

I have tried it both by simple html and svg but I am not able to fill the entire div with the text.

```
<div class="Charting" id="MetricContainer" style="height:100%;width:100%;"><svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 225"><text x="50%" y="75%" fill="#00000" style="text-anchor:middle;font-size:150px">8</text></svg></div>

<h1 style="font-size:20vh;text-align:center;position: relati;text-anchor:middle">Text</h1>
```

I need help in making the svg responsive and using all div area.

Currently I get this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zTJ4.jpg)

I am looking for some thins like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOVro.jpg)

Comment: Share your working HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/byjk0x67/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you have created the SVG.  If we draw the SVG by itself, with a coloured background, you can see that the "8" is centred in a much larger SVG canvas.

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 225"><text x="50%" y="75%" fill="#00000" style="text-anchor:middle;font-size:150px">8</text></svg>
```

What you probably want to do is position the text closer to the top left and adjust the `viewBox` so it has a much closer fit around the text.

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 75 120"><text x="0" y="110" fill="#00000" style="font-size:150px">8</text></svg>
```

Try using this version of the SVG in your page.

Note that I have left a bit of a margin around the "8", to match your second image. You can adjust it even tighter if you wish.